# can't get out of wireframe mode

Tags: wireframe

for some reason my mesh is only visible as a wireframe. I would like to get it back to a solid or textured view. Any suggestions?[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL,DR:

In your screenshot, check Maximum Draw Type. You have it at Wire. Change it to Textured.

### Long version

Max. Draw Type (as you have noticed) allows you to reduce the visualization quality at the object level.
It is useful to control the level of detail while you're editing your scene. Set objects you don't want to bother with to Wire or even Box, and keep those you want to see in full detail Textured.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Display*, choose *Solid* instead of *Wire*. It allows you to display your object as a Wire only.

[image]

Comment: Would be good in future to add extra context to your answer(s) explaining what this option is and why it works (see other answer for a good example of this).